# PayPal Billing Plan meaning of frequency, frequency_interval and cycles

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

It's not clear enough how these three parameters work for billing plan:

1. frequency
2. frequency_interval
3. cycles

I assume that it works in following way:

(A) frequency=MONTH + frequency_interval=2 + cycles=3 + amount={10 USD} -> subscriber will be charged 3 times every second month for 10 USD each time (3x10usd payments within 6 months)

(B) frequency=YEAR + frequency_interval=1 + cycles=1 + amount={100 USD} -> subscriber will be charged 1 time for 100 USD in the moment of subscription creation (100usd payment for 1 year)

Am I correct?

Comment: Can't wonder why Stripe has grown so much when you go back to Paypal's API 

Answer (score 5):

Your're correct,

For A) if your customers signup on JAN means, according to your value set, first payment will done on JAN, second on MAR, third on JUN for 10 USD per month

For B) If your customer signup on JAN, first payment will done on JAN and for the whole year it will be 100 USD.

Comment: Thanks. Let's wait for 1-2 more approves from different persons in order to be sure for 100% :)